# Unable to boot from LiveUSB on Razer 2017 Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, usb, uefi

I'd like to install Ubuntu 17.04 which has the 4.13 kernel alongside Windows 10 on my fancy dancy new Razer Blade Kaby Lake so that I have an OS I know and love. I followed the instructions [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows?_ga=2.39437798.496988718.1507228947-951022611.1505587850#0) and seem to have a working bootable drive that appears in the boot menu when I restart my machine, but selecting it does nothing. I've disabled FastBoot and SecureBoot in my BIOS and also tried switching the boot order of the devices (making my hard-drive boot option 2 and the removable USB boot option 1) but I still can't boot from the USB device. A few details about the machine:

Razer Blade Pro 2017 (Kaby Lake)

Windows 10

Aptio 2017

Any tips or suggestions much appreciated, thanks!

edit-

Thanks for the pointers to [this](https://insider.razerzone.com/index.php?threads/ubuntu-16-04-or-17-04-or-for-kaby-lake-razer-blade.23814/) I had read that and unless I'm reading it wrong, the suggestion is to use a kernel version higher than 4.11. As Ubuntu 17.10 has kernel 4.13 I don't think it helps here (happy to be proven wrong though).

Comment: This may help: https://insider.razerzone.com/index.php?threads/ubuntu-16-04-or-17-04-or-for-kaby-lake-razer-blade.23814/

Comment: 17.10 has kernel 4.13, but 17.04 has 4.10.

Comment: @mikewhatever Aww this is just dumb on my part: you're totally right and I am trying to use 17.04 not 17.10 (more coffee needed). So, does it seem right that I've got to upgrade a 17.04 to 4.11 to even boot on my machine? Looks like I'll be learning how to do that w/o a Linux box of any kind.

Comment: Just get a [daily ISO  of 17.10](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/).

Comment: Use the legacy boot. Not UEFI boot. I had that problem when I tried to boot from a CD.  Found out I had to create a UEFI CD but first, a Dell Rep told me to disable the UEFI and I was able to boot a legacy CD. I was trying to boot an old Clonezilla disk. When I downloaded a new 64 bit one, it was UEFI and was bootable.

Comment: If the computer came pre-installed with Windows 10, chances are you should ***NOT*** use BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting, contrary to jpezz's advice! Doing so will create problems that will have to be corrected later. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for details. If you can boot the installer in BIOS mode but not in EFI mode, chances are the installer has been improperly prepared. Details are on the page I just referenced.

Comment: @RodSmith thanks for the link. I was also warned away from CSM, unfortunately I can't boot it in either mode. I'm inclined to blame Rufus as that's what the Ubuntu tutorial I was following recommended.

Comment: Rufus is one of the better tools for preparing bootable USB drives of Ubuntu installers; however, it's worth trying another tool or two. If that doesn't work, then it could be your computer is not (yet) compatible with Ubuntu, in which case you might have to wait or try another distribution. If you try another one, try something completely unrelated, like Fedora or Arch; distributions like Mint are derivative of Ubuntu and use the same kernel, which means they're unlikely to fix Ubuntu compatibility issues. Adding kernel options may help, too, but I have no specific suggestions of what to try.